# Why writing timestamp before 1900 year on spark-3 does not throw SparkUpgradeException?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

On page:
https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/whats-new-apache-spark-3-proleptic-calendar-date-time-management/read
We can read:

> reading dates before 1582-10-15 or
> timestamps before 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z from Parquet files can be ambiguous,
> as the files may be written by Spark 2.x or legacy versions of Hive,
> which uses a legacy hybrid calendar that
> is different from Spark 3.0+'s Proleptic Gregorian calendar

Please consider a following scenario where exception is not thrown:

```
scala> spark.conf.get("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite")
res27: String = EXCEPTION
scala> Seq(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("1899-01-01 00:00:00")).toDF("col").write.parquet("/tmp/someDate")
scala> // why did not it throw exception?
```

While as for dates before `1582` exception is thrown:

```
scala> Seq(java.sql.Date.valueOf("1581-01-01")).toDF("col").write.parquet("/tmp/someOtherDate")
21/03/10 19:07:19 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: writing dates before 1582-10-15 or timestamps before 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z into Parquet files can be dangerous, as the files may be read by Spark 2.x or legacy versions of Hive later, which uses a legacy hybrid calendar that is different from Spark 3.0+'s Proleptic Gregorian calendar. See more details in SPARK-31404. You can set spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite to 'LEGACY' to rebase the datetime values w.r.t. the calendar difference during writing, to get maximum interoperability. Or set spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite to 'CORRECTED' to write the datetime values as it is, if you are 100% sure that the written files will only be read by Spark 3.0+ or other systems that use Proleptic Gregorian calendar.
```

Can someone explain this difference?

Answer (score 0):

I have spark 3.1.2 version I have tested both scenarios and the exception is thrown in both cases...please refer to below:

```
scala> Seq(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("1899-01-01 00:00:00")).toDF("col").write.parquet("/tmp/someDate")
22/01/04 18:03:53 ERROR Utils: Aborting task                        (0 + 1) / 1]
org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: writing dates before 1582-10-15 or timestamps before 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z into Parquet INT96 files can be dangerous, as the files may be read by Spark 2.x or legacy versions of Hive later, which uses a legacy hybrid calendar that is different from Spark 3.0+'s Proleptic Gregorian calendar. See more details in SPARK-31404. You can set spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite to 'LEGACY' to rebase the datetime values w.r.t. the calendar difference during writing, to get maximum interoperability. Or set spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite to 'CORRECTED' to write the datetime values as it is, if you are 100% sure that the written files will only be read by Spark 3.0+ or other systems that use Proleptic Gregorian calendar. here
```

Also second scenario:

```
scala> Seq(java.sql.Date.valueOf("1581-01-01")).toDF("col").write.parquet("/tmp/someOtherDate1")
22/01/04 18:05:08 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: writing dates before 1582-10-15 or timestamps before 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z into Parquet files can be dangerous, as the files may be read by Spark 2.x or legacy versions of Hive later, which uses a legacy hybrid calendar that is different from Spark 3.0+'s Proleptic Gregorian calendar. See more details in SPARK-31404. You can set spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite to 'LEGACY' to rebase the datetime values w.r.t. the calendar difference during writing, to get maximum interoperability. Or set spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite to 'CORRECTED' to write the datetime values as it is, if you are 100% sure that the written files will only be read by Spark 3.0+ or other systems that use Proleptic Gregorian calendar.
```